# Override native js file

Tags: magento2, overrides

Simple issue : What should I do in order to override a native js file.

In that specific case : `src/vendor/magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-frontend-ui/view/frontend/web/js/configurable-variation-qty.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes you want to do can be performed using mixin, create one following the steps - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html

If you want to overide and call your file instead of core file-

Place file in you theme on path
i.e

src/app/design/frontend/Theme_vendor/Theme_name/Magento_Inventory_Configurable_Product_Frontend_Ui/web/js/configurable-variation-qty.js

and add the required changes.

Hope that helps.